# Can't cp files to Google Object Storage via gsutil

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm sure I granted all the permissions that I can give:

```
louchenyao@dev ~> gcloud auth list
                  Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
*       290002171211-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
        louchenyao@gmail.com

To set the active account, run:
    $ gcloud config set account `ACCOUNT`

louchenyao@dev ~> curl -H 'Metadata-Flavor: Google' "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/scopes"
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append
louchenyao@dev ~> gsutil cp pgrc.sh gs://hidden-buckets-name
Copying file://pgrc.sh [Content-Type=text/x-sh]...
AccessDeniedException: 403 Insufficient Permission
```

And I have granted [Storage Admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duGHg.png) to cloud computing default account.

If I switch to my personal account, it works. So I'm wondering if I missed some important permissions.

Comment: Which scopes are enabled for the instance? Make sure that you have enbled "Storage Read Write" OR "Storage Full". I recommend using IAM roles instead of Scopes. Set "Allow full access to all Cloud APIs". Then control permissions using IAM roles.

Comment: Also: remember that after granting those scopes, you restart your instance.

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough - Thank you. You don't have to restart the instance, you have to shutdown the instance first to change the scopes. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks. But I'm curious why set scope to devstorage.read_write is not enough.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by `is not enough`. The way that permissions work with GCE instances. First you attach IAM permissions to the service account that GCE uses. You can reduce these permissions using Scopes but you cannot add permissions using Scopes that the service account does not already have.

Comment: @JohnHanley Ok, I got that. I didn't add IAM role before, so set the scopes to read/write storage won't work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To grant access to write to the bucket from VM Instance, using default service account:
[change API access scopes for the VM instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes), follow these steps:

- `Stop` the instance
- Enter `VM instance details` > `Edit`
- Change `Cloud API access scopes` > `Storage: Full`
- `Save` changes and start the instance

It is also possible to set [access scopes](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts?hl=en_US&_ga=2.144798644.-125532137.1551689756#accesscopesiam) creating VM instance in the `Identity and API access` section of the console

If you do not want to use default service account, [create new service account for your VM Instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances), and use it to access bucket.

---